# Angular handle post request with IDM

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have an angular application which is hosted inside another C# MVC app(HostApp) as iframe . These apps are secured via identityserver4(IDM).

User login to host app and we get JWT token from Idm. Now in order to establish handshake between Hostapp and iframed angular app I have to pass this JWT token. Once anagular app receives this token it should communicate with IDM (introspect end point) to check token .

Now My problem is how to setup communication between host app -> Angular -> IDM , since I want to send JWT token from host app to angular via post request but how this request will be handled at angular side I am getting stuck on , Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you answer these to help me understand ur problem: 1. Is the MVC app (HostApp) just responsible to host the angular app? 2. If not what else is does? 3. On IdentityServer4, did you register mvc as a client or the angular app - feel free to post the client's config 5. do you use oidc client lib on angular or not?

Comment: 1& 2. Is the MVC app (HostApp) just responsible to host the angular app? - It does more than hosting angular application . Its more of enterprise C# MVC Web application which house bunch of different applications and perform common features such as authentication , SSO and other business specific functions  3. On IdentityServer4, did you register mvc as a client or the angular app - Both of these applications are registered as two separate client on IDM side  5. do you use oidc client lib on angular or not?  - Yes I am using OIDC client and it works perfectly with IDM if i have todirectlylogin

Comment: MVC host app & angular are both clients, each will authenticate through IDS4 as a client, for example if you use code grant on angular, you can use the received access token(jwt) to call an authorized resource on MVC - I'm not sure why you need to send the jwt token from mvc to angular